How to handle day light saving time change in Oracle?
I have a table used by several users in different places around the world and where a user may store the start date & time of a project.
Let's say we are in March 2024 in Frankfurt, Germany. The user may want choose the date of May 1st at 8 o'clock as the start date.

When the session is in March (GMT + 1), the start date is stored as a TimeStamp : May, 1st, 8h00

Now when time moves forward and we are in may after daylight saving change (GMT + 2), the date shows May, 1st, 9h00 (which quite normal).


But this creates ambiguity for users. When a user says a task has to start at 8h. It should always show 8h. No matter when it was inserted and the date of the year we are in.
For this case, the user should have inserted May 1st, 07h00, so that when in May, the date will show May 1st, 08h00. But this will be very complex for users to understand (and to develop also)
Is there any way I can store the date such as that It reflects the correct time in the present and in the future ?
I'm thinking about storing the date as char such that it will always be seen the same way regardless of the dates and the period of the year. But that's too hardcore.

Have you looked at either storing the value as a timestamp with [local] time zone, or normalised to UTC before storing as a plain timestamp and adjusting to local time zone for display? Or are you saying the stored historic time appears to change based on the current day's DST - in which case is it implicitly being converted to a local time zone, but incorrectly?

Dates should never be stored as text, it's a design flaw.

In case you use TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE and you need to use an index on this column, have a look at https://tonyhasler.wordpress.com/2010/09/04/tonys-tirade-against-timestamp-with-time-zone/

@WernfriedDomscheit That's a blog from 2010 discussing some issues with Oracle 10 and 11g. Even then, some of the issues being discussed are because the writer is lazy and is comparing a TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE to SYSDATE - 1/24 which relies on an implicit cast and is not using SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1' HOUR which would not require such a cast just so they don't have to type a few extra characters. (I'm not saying prefer WITH TIME ZONE over WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE, I'm just saying the blog is very dated and in some cases trying to justify bad practices.)

@MT0 fully agree, the blog is fairly negative and has a few mistakes. The main point is when you create an index on TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE column then Oracle cannot create the index directly. Instead Oracle creates  virtual column of SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(...) and index this column. Thus all your queries also should look like WHERE SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(tsCol) .... Once you are aware of that, data type TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE is very useful.

Either store the dates and times as:

TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE; or
DATE or TIMESTAMP (without time zone) and ensure that the dates/times are always entered in the UTC time zone.

In both cases, when you want to display the date and time to the user then you can convert from the stored time zone to the user's local time zone.
You should NOT store dates and times as strings.
Example 1 - Storing values as TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE
If you have the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (datetime TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE);

INSERT INTO table_name  (datetime)
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2024-05-01 08:00:00 Europe/Berlin' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2024-05-01 08:00:00 Europe/London' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2024-01-01 08:00:00 UTC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2024-07-01 08:00:00 UTC' FROM DUAL;

Then, if you are in Germany:
ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Berlin';

Then you can get the dates/times as either the local time or the UTC time using:
SELECT datetime,
       datetime AT LOCAL AS local_datetime,
       datetime AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS utc_datetime
FROM   table_name;

Which outputs:



DATETIME
LOCAL_DATETIME
UTC_DATETIME




2024-05-01 08:00:00.000000 EUROPE/BERLIN
2024-05-01 08:00:00.000000 EUROPE/BERLIN
2024-05-01 06:00:00.000000 UTC


2024-05-01 08:00:00.000000 EUROPE/LONDON
2024-05-01 09:00:00.000000 EUROPE/BERLIN
2024-05-01 07:00:00.000000 UTC


2024-01-01 08:00:00.000000 UTC
2024-01-01 09:00:00.000000 EUROPE/BERLIN
2024-01-01 08:00:00.000000 UTC


2024-07-01 08:00:00.000000 UTC
2024-07-01 10:00:00.000000 EUROPE/BERLIN
2024-07-01 08:00:00.000000 UTC



If you connected as someone in America and wanted to see the same data, using the same query:
ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York';

SELECT datetime,
       datetime AT LOCAL AS local_datetime,
       datetime AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS utc_datetime
FROM   table_name;

Then the output is:



DATETIME
LOCAL_DATETIME
UTC_DATETIME




2024-05-01 08:00:00.000000 EUROPE/BERLIN
2024-05-01 02:00:00.000000 AMERICA/NEW_YORK
2024-05-01 06:00:00.000000 UTC


2024-05-01 08:00:00.000000 EUROPE/LONDON
2024-05-01 03:00:00.000000 AMERICA/NEW_YORK
2024-05-01 07:00:00.000000 UTC


2024-01-01 08:00:00.000000 UTC
2024-01-01 03:00:00.000000 AMERICA/NEW_YORK
2024-01-01 08:00:00.000000 UTC


2024-07-01 08:00:00.000000 UTC
2024-07-01 04:00:00.000000 AMERICA/NEW_YORK
2024-07-01 08:00:00.000000 UTC



In both cases, the timestamps in the UTC time zone are identical and the local timestamp show the timestamps adjusted to the local time zone; you do not need to manually adjust either as the database will handle conversions between time zones (including DST) automatically.
Example 2 - Storing the values as DATE in the UTC time zone.
If you have the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name2 (datetime DATE);

INSERT INTO table_name2 (datetime)
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2024-05-01 08:00:00 Europe/Berlin' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2024-05-01 08:00:00 Europe/London' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2024-01-01 08:00:00 UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2024-07-01 08:00:00 UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' FROM DUAL;

Then:
ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Berlin';

SELECT datetime,
       FROM_TZ(CAST(datetime AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') AT LOCAL AS local_datetime,
       FROM_TZ(CAST(datetime AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') AS utc_datetime
FROM   table_name2;

Outputs:



DATETIME
LOCAL_DATETIME
UTC_DATETIME




2024-05-01 06:00:00
2024-05-01 08:00:00.000000 EUROPE/BERLIN
2024-05-01 06:00:00.000000 UTC


2024-05-01 07:00:00
2024-05-01 09:00:00.000000 EUROPE/BERLIN
2024-05-01 07:00:00.000000 UTC


2024-01-01 08:00:00
2024-01-01 09:00:00.000000 EUROPE/BERLIN
2024-01-01 08:00:00.000000 UTC


2024-07-01 08:00:00
2024-07-01 10:00:00.000000 EUROPE/BERLIN
2024-07-01 08:00:00.000000 UTC



and, the same data and same query executed in a session in a different time zone:
ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York';

SELECT datetime,
       FROM_TZ(CAST(datetime AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') AT LOCAL AS local_datetime,
       FROM_TZ(CAST(datetime AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') AS utc_datetime
FROM   table_name2;

Outputs:



DATETIME
LOCAL_DATETIME
UTC_DATETIME




2024-05-01 06:00:00
2024-05-01 02:00:00.000000 AMERICA/NEW_YORK
2024-05-01 06:00:00.000000 UTC


2024-05-01 07:00:00
2024-05-01 03:00:00.000000 AMERICA/NEW_YORK
2024-05-01 07:00:00.000000 UTC


2024-01-01 08:00:00
2024-01-01 03:00:00.000000 AMERICA/NEW_YORK
2024-01-01 08:00:00.000000 UTC


2024-07-01 08:00:00
2024-07-01 04:00:00.000000 AMERICA/NEW_YORK
2024-07-01 08:00:00.000000 UTC



Again the time zone changes (including DST) are handled automatically.
fiddle

Apart from MT0 answer I propose a third option: TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE
Basically it is the same as "TIMESTAMP and ensure that the dates/times are always entered in the UTC time zone."
However,

ensure that the dates/times are always entered in the UTC time zone and
convert from the stored time zone to the user's local time zone

are done automatically by Oracle, you need less code.
CREATE TABLE table_name3 (datetime TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE);

INSERT INTO table_name3 (datetime)
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2024-05-01 08:00:00 Europe/Berlin' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2024-05-01 08:00:00 Europe/London' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2024-01-01 08:00:00 UTC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2024-07-01 08:00:00 UTC' FROM DUAL;


ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Berlin';

SELECT datetime as local_datetime
FROM table_name3;




LOCAL_DATETIME




2024-05-01 08:00:00


2024-05-01 09:00:00


2024-01-01 09:00:00


2024-07-01 10:00:00



TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE values are stored internally at DBTIMEZONE which defaults to UTC. But actually it does not matter and you don't need to take care about that.
